# Android Volley JSONObjectRequest in Fragment outputs nothing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I'm trying to build a ListView (who's inside a Fragment) with getting
data from an external url.

I'm using Volley to do this request, but when I try to run the app, it shows nothing.

Here's the Fragment code:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final List<NewsFeed> newsFeed = new ArrayList<>();

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://webservice_url/", null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                     JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("data");

                     NewsFeed feed = new NewsFeed(obj.getString("title"), obj.getString("description"), obj.getString("date"));
                     newsFeed.add(feed);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);

    ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.newsFeed);
    NewsFeedAdapter adapter = new NewsFeedAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList<NewsFeed>) newsFeed);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here is the NewsFeed class and the Adapter:

```
    public class NewsFeed {
    public String title;
    public String description;
    public String date;

    public NewsFeed(String title, String description, String date) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.date = date;
    }
}

public class NewsFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsFeed> {
    // View lookup cache
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        TextView date;
    }

    public NewsFeedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsFeed> newsFeedArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.fragment_dashboard_news, newsFeedArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        NewsFeed newsFeed = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard_news, parent, false);

            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.title.setText(newsFeed.title);
        viewHolder.description.setText(newsFeed.description);
        viewHolder.date.setText(newsFeed.date);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Also, when I add elements without the Volley request it's working.

Comment: In `onResponse( )` you need to update the listView. Do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged( )`  right after populating `newsFeed`. Try it out  :)

Comment: Sir, you made my day ! This is perfectly working now, THANK YOU !!!

Comment: I will add this as an answer then  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Original Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984280/android-volley-jsonobjectrequest-in-fragment-outputs-nothing?noredirect=1#comment55724437_33984280)**

In `onResponse( )` you need to update the listView. Do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged( )` right after populating `newsFeed`. Try it out :)